# Sharepoint Workflow not Triggered when item is edited by another workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a Sharepoint Designer workflow that triggers when an item is added. 
The workflow changes a field in the Item and creates a task for Approval.
A second workflow is also attached to the same list for edit item event.

The second workflow is not triggered when the first workflow changes the list item field. 
How to trigger the second workflow.
When Action is taken on the Approval request of the first workflow then the second workflow is triggering.
Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 -> first workflow should be in workflow 2013 ->set on item start and update

step 2 -> second workflow should be in workflow 2010 -> set on item update -> after that set your desire functionality in workflow ->**(next line is magic line. This line will stop your workflow to run in continues loop/deadlock) add Stop workflow activity after your functionality done**

Stop workflow activity only available in SPWF 2010.

Thanks,
Enjoy SharePoint
Hardik Akbari